# Can jQuery.filter work on the body tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am filtering an ajax response using jQuery to extract the body of a page that is returned and replace the current page. I discovered that if I filter the response on 'body' it returns nothing.

For example, to emulate this in the console on this page I can run:

```
$($('html').html()).filter('body')
```

which returns:

```
[]
```

However, if I run:

```
$($('html').html()).filter('title')
```

I get:

```
[<title>​Can jQuery.filter work on the body tag? - Stack Overflow​</title>​]
```

Anyone know why or if this is a bug?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing `filter()` with `find()`? And why the `html()` call? Following `$("html").find("body")` works just fine...

Comment: I'm operating on a string returned from an ajax request, so filter works while find returns nothing.

Comment: I think they are confusing it. For the OP: filter() takes all matched elements in the first selector (i.e. <html> in your case, so one result) and returns all elements that you specify to filter, which is <title> - none. .find() will look through all descendants of <html> and find <title> elements.

Comment: Well then a good question to ask is why does `filter()` "works"? Examine `$($('html').html())` to answer that question.

Comment: Great question, and yes this explains it, body doesn't exist in this set. I am working on data returned from an ajax request, so `$(data).find('title')` will return nothing, where data is the response data from the ajax request. However `$(data).filter('title')` returns the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to answer a bit more in detail: the real problem here is that `$()` is used to wrap the string coming from `$("html").html()`. according to the jQuery documentation:

Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed. (so in one browser you might find the title in the other not)

as soon as you use `$` around a string you gain a parsed collection... but that may remove some of the data you wanna use... two body elements are not allowed in one document

But $("html").children().filter("body") will work, so generally speaking I would answer your question with yes, it can

I think you already found a solution ;) but just to have it mentioned:
I would highly recommend to skip the `$` call and simply use native methods like substring and indexOf

```
// try in the browser console
var myString = "<html><head></head><body>foobar</body></html>";
myString.substring(myString.indexOf("<body>"), myString.indexOf("</body>") + 7);
"<body>foobar</body>"
```

It should work the exact same way for an ajax response since it is a pure string. If there is no need to extract the body tag:

```
// try in the browser console
var myString = "<html><head></head><body>foobar</body></html>";
myString.substring(myString.indexOf("<body>") + 6, myString.indexOf("</body>"));
"foobar"
```

NOTE: when looking at performance the native operation performs in less than half of the time that is needed for the rewrap of the `.html()` and calling `.filter()`

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Yes indeed, I ended up splitting on the body tag `(data.split(/<\/*body.*>/))[1]` to get a similar result.

Comment: looks even nicer :)... i am not sure which performs faster... but anyway using native methods on strings is way better than trying to achieve this via any library :)